# Can't get VS2010 RC to print in color

Tags: visual-studio, printing, visual-studio-2010

Is it just me or will VS2010 RC not print code in color? I have tried everything I can think of to no avail, everything prints monochrome.

I have the latest drivers for my printer
VS2008 prints color just fine (As do other apps)
I tested printing in high quality color, normal and ink saver modes.
Class Diagrams DO print in color making me think it is not a driver issue.

Is there an option or something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently colour printing functionality will be absent in the VS 2010 release initially. I found this [info on a msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcprerelease/thread/2018079c-4896-45b2-affd-6620483c88e6).

Comment: Wow, I would love to see the resoning behind this. Since the editor is in WPF and printing from WPF is supposed to be a lot easier than it was before. It would be great to see the gotcha that keeps Microsoft from being able to do it!

Comment: I thought I would try using the Expression blend preview to print it but no such luck, it does not work with 2010 RC

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround to print the specific file I wanted. I cannot be certain it would always work.

The solution was to open the .cs file (Not the whole solution) in VS 2008. I also tested a .xaml file and it printed fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

While the answer has been accepted for this and it is linked via the MSDN forum post in the accepted answer I thought I'd post an update here as this is one of the top Google results for this question.

To enable colour printing in VS2010 you will need to download the [Color Printing extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/00ec88c2-1553-47d2-8170-3c5baa0c6e44). Note that as this is an extension it means that you can not print in colour on VS2010 Express Edition.

Answer (score 0):

For those still looking for this, Microsoft has released a patch to VS2010 Professional and up (sorry - no love for Express users).

The download is here:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/00ec88c2-1553-47d2-8170-3c5baa0c6e44/

I've tested it, and it does work.